# how do get the first 'column' in calling REST API?

Tags: api, rest

I am currently developing reports where a get REST API in a specific site, the REST API shows below

```
"people_id": 17288681,
    "name": "Steve",
    "email": "steve@mail.com",
    "job_title": "Manager",
    "department": {
        "department_id": 16834000,
        "name": "USA"
    },
    "notes": null,
    "auto_email": 1,
    "employee_type": 1,
```

My issues is, there are two columns named "name". one for the name of the person and one for the name of department.

Is there a way for me to only GET the name of the people based on the "people_id"?

in my code in GETs the "name" of department becauset hats the last line that has the "name" column"

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This entirely depends on your code.
Without knowing the API, we cannot say if there is a solution to *just* get the person name. This would then be something the API has to have implemented.

If you have a JSON parser included in your code however, you can simply get the object field. One of them would be `obj['name']` (or similar, depends on your language) while another would be `obj['department']['name']`